# Routing Mobile connections for multiple uplinks

Tags: networking, routing, lte

I have a MBIM LTE modem with 2 network interfaces (one is a VLAN) and I am trying to configure both connections, given that IPs, Gateways, etc. are obtained through MBIM protocol, so the routing is to be done manually.
Googling a lot and searching in this forum, the solution seemd to be [this one](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html), namely using a second and third routing table and routing rules.

This solution is usually suggested for eth network devices, but I assume there should be no difference, however I can not get to make both networks to work together and in the best case I can ping from the 1st interface only, while the vlan does not ping at all.

My configuration is the following:

Let's say the MBIM protocol gives the following data for the two connections

```
Session 1
IP=10.39.187.213/24
GW=10.39.187.1

Session 2
IP=5.91.204.208/24
GW=5.91.204.1
```

This is the routing

```
ip link add link wwp0s20u1u1u4 name wwp0s20u1u1u4.0 type vlan id 0
ip set link wwp0s20u1u1u4 up

ip route show table main
default
    nexthop via 10.39.187.1  dev wwp0s20u1u1u4 weight 1
    nexthop via 5.91.204.1  dev wwp0s20u1u1u4.0 weight 1
5.91.204.0/24 dev wwp0s20u1u1u4.0  proto kernel  scope link  src 5.91.204.208
10.39.187.0/24 dev wwp0s20u1u1u4  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.39.187.213

ip route show table second
default via 10.39.187.1 dev wwp0s20u1u1u4
10.39.187.0/24 dev wwp0s20u1u1u4  scope link  src 10.39.187.213

ip route show table third
default via 5.91.204.1 dev wwp0s20u1u1u4.0
5.91.204.0/24 dev wwp0s20u1u1u4.0  scope link  src 5.91.204.208

ip rule
0:  from all lookup local
32762:  from all to 5.91.204.0/24 lookup third
32763:  from 5.91.204.0/24 lookup third
32764:  from all to 10.39.187.0/24 lookup second
32765:  from 10.39.187.0/24 lookup second
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

This is the result of the pings

```
ping -I wwp0s20u1u1u4 8.8.8.8 -c 4
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 10.39.187.213 wwp0s20u1u1u4: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=42 time=121 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=42 time=79.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=42 time=111 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=42 time=110 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 79.458/105.839/121.511/15.807 ms


ping -I wwp0s20u1u1u4.0 8.8.8.8 -c 4
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 5.91.204.208 wwp0s20u1u1u4.0: 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3023ms
```

UPDATE:
With a QMI modem that exposes 2 RMNETs this very same configuration works. I wonder how to debug the VLAN network of this use case.